# Import Data from scraping into CSV

Tags: python, csv, screen-scraping

I'm using pycharm and Python 3.7.

I would like to write data in a csv, but my code writes in the File just the first line of my data... someone knows why?

This is my code:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import csv


 pytrend = TrendReq()
 pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['auto model A', 
 'auto model C'])


# Interest Over Time
interest_over_time_df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
print(interest_over_time_df.head(100))



writer=csv.writer(open("C:\\Users\\
Desktop\\Data\\c.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8'))

writer.writerow(interest_over_time_df)
```

Comment: You do see that you have put in the code just to write a single row by executing `writer.writerow` not in a loop.

Comment: @Pdf , which version of python you are using?

Comment: @pygo Python 3.7

Comment: Okay, if you are checking with usual `with open` then try the answer i posted that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
interest_over_time_df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: Just for my curiosity, can I avoid pandas' import?

Comment: @PdF, you can't avoid pandas import if you are using its functions and attributes, but yes you can in case you don't want use pandas.

Comment: Ok I know this, but when I paste your code the import is underline in red because I don't call the library in the code...

Comment: @Pdf , you have to import pandas if you are first extracting data frame out of it.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Once i encountered the same problem and solve it like below:

```
with open("file.csv",  "rb", encoding="utf-8) as fh:
```

precise details:

```
r = read mode
b =  mode specifier in the open() states that the file shall be treated as binary, 
so contents will remain a bytes. No decoding attempt will happen this way.
```

As we know python tries to convert a byte-array (a bytes which it assumes to be a utf-8-encoded string) to a unicode string (str). This process of course is a decoding according to utf-8 rules. When it tries this, it encounters a byte sequence which is not allowed in utf-8-encoded strings (namely this 0xff at position 0).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
import csv
with open(<path to output_csv>, "wb") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in interest_over_time_df:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Read more here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

You need to loop over the data and write in line by line